# converting code from bufferedreader to scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

How would I go about changing this code to utilize the Scanner class instead of BufferedReader? Also, if I change the code to use the Scanner, would I then not need the InputStreamReader?

Thanks in advance!

Below is some of my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.GregorianCalendar; 
import java.text.DateFormat;

int day = 0;
int month = 0;
int year = 0;
while(true) {
  // Read in a date
   System.out.print("\nEnter the year: ");
  year = readInt();
  while(true){
    System.out.print("\nEnter the month number\n(January is 1, December is 12): ");
    month = readInt();
    if(validMonth(--month))                                        // Change month to zero-based and validate
      break;
  }
  while(true) {
    System.out.print("\nEnter the day number\nin the month: ");
    day = readInt();
    if(validDay(day, month, year)) {                               // Verify date is valid for month and year
        break;
    }
  }

  // Try another date?
  System.out.println("\n\nDo you want to try another date? (Enter Y or N)");
  if(!yes()) {
    break;
  }
}   }
// Reads an integer from the keyboard   private static int readInt() {
int value = 0;
while(true) {
  try {
    value = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine().trim());
    return value;
  }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input.\nPlease try again.");
  } catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println("Error reading for the keyboard." + e.getMessage());
  }
}   }
private static boolean yes() {
String str = null;
while(true) {
  try {
    str = in.readLine().trim();
  } catch(IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Error reading for the keyboard." + e.getMessage());
  }

  if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
    return true;
  } else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
    break;
  } else {
    System.out.print("Invalid input.\nPlease try again. Enter Y or N: ");
  }
}
return false;   }
private static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));         // Keyboard input
// Date formatter for displaying dates   private static DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);   }
```

Comment: `while(true) { doSomething(); if (condition) break; }` is the same as `do { doSomething(); } while (!condition);`

Comment: instead of `bufferedReader.readline()` use `scanner.nextLine()`